# Not able to detect text from other application window using accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibility

I created an accessibilty service and when I enable the service from settings service is getting connected.

What I need to know is if I tap on any screen point outside my applications,
Window text of surrounding should be detected something similar to U-dictionary.

```
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused|typeAllMask"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:notificationTimeout="0"
```

Now I see randomly method is fired, but I need to be sure about the event.

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
```

Could you please suggest what event i should handle when I click on point or finger up on a point.
Also to detect the text from surroundings.